LORA demodulation
I am writing a course project on demodulating the test signal of the LORA system with CSS-modulation. SF=8, BW=500 kHz. I can't figure it out. I stopped at the level of dechirping. I make an exact shift of the carrier frequency to zero, then I localize the symbols, that is, I set the number of samples per symbol and divide the array of signal samples into symbols. Next I do multiplication my chirps with generated down-chirps (dechirp=symbol*np.conj(raw_chirp).. But then I can't understand how to correlate the received dechirped symbols with the symbols transmitted by the system. That is, in theory we have 2sf frequency levels. How to determine which frequency belongs to which transmitted symbol. I saw somewhere symbol=np.argmax(fft(symbol), n=2sf) but with this method I can't find the sync words 0x34 or 0x12. I really need your help.

maybe this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UYhUi8SiK4&list=PLbBQHMnVMR42yZ7aTlMAJyXD_5VmUZjWZ&index=1
